# How to edit and update number on same player?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cashapelayer

my app part is based on canvas.

**#What I want to do?**

I need dictionary to track and save particular player's key and value.because, I want to store player1 on key "1" and player2 on key "2", suppose user change player 2's number, then player 2's number change not key "2".

I can place multiple players (cashapelayers - with text),
on imageview. and can edit text label on double click for same player.

**my issue is,** whenever i click second time on same player, it shows wrong number, as well when click okay it creates new player.
what i want is to edit a player's label(number) with different number,
and don't create a new one till I click on imageview.

I have try to create playerview in touchedEnded but I'm fail, also try to search for the same issue on other resources.

I have added some images for reference.
[image: players on imageview][image: add different player number]
[image: player number edit success]
[image: when click player 22 it shows as player 2]
[image: when click ok on alertview it creates new player]

```
class AddPlayerStruct {
    
    var addPlayerViewStruct : AddPlayerView?
    var addPlayerViewsArrStruct : [AddPlayerView] = []
    var Label = UILabel()
    
}
```

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //MARK: AddPlayerView Variables
    
    var addPlayerView : AddPlayerView?
    var addPlayerViews: [AddPlayerView] = []
    var draggedAddPlayer: AddPlayerView?
    let addPlayerWidth : CGFloat = 40
    
    var addPlayerDict : [String : AddPlayerStruct] = [:]
    var playerCount : Int = 1
    
    var label = UILabel()
    var isDobuleClick : Bool = false
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var images: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        guard let draggedAddPlayer = draggedAddPlayer, let point = touches.first?.location(in: images) else {
            return
        }
        draggedAddPlayer.center = point
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        // Do nothing if a circle is being dragged
        // or if we do not have a coordinate
        guard draggedAddPlayer == nil, let point = touches.first?.location(in: images) else {
            return
        }
        
        // Do not create new circle if touch is in an existing circle
        // Keep the reference of the (potentially) dragged circle
        if let draggedAddPlayer = addPlayerViews.filter({ UIBezierPath(ovalIn: $0.frame).contains(point) }).first {
            
            self.draggedAddPlayer = draggedAddPlayer
            return
        }
        
        
        // Create new circle and store in dict
        let rect = CGRect(x: point.x - 20, y: point.y - 20, width: addPlayerWidth, height: addPlayerWidth)
        addPlayerView = AddPlayerView(frame: rect)
        addPlayerView?.backgroundColor = .white
        addPlayerView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addPlayerView?.image = UIImage(named: "player")
        addPlayerView?.tintColor = .systemBlue
        
        
        addPlayerViews.append(addPlayerView!)
        images.addSubview(addPlayerView!)
        
        // The newly created view can be immediately dragged
        draggedAddPlayer = addPlayerView
        
        //Add Player label as Number
        //        playerCount = addPlayerDict.count + 1
        
        var addPlayerStruct = AddPlayerStruct()
        
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: rect.width / 2 - 8, y: rect.height / 2 + 5, width: 16, height: 10))
        
        if addPlayerStruct.Label.text == nil{
            label.text = String(addPlayerDict.count + 1)
        }
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica" , size: 10)
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addPlayerView!.addSubview(label)
        
        
        debugPrint(addPlayerDict)
        
        
        addPlayerStruct.addPlayerViewStruct = addPlayerView
        addPlayerStruct.addPlayerViewsArrStruct.append(contentsOf: addPlayerViews)
        
        addPlayerDict.updateValue(addPlayerStruct, forKey: String(addPlayerDict.count + 1))
        debugPrint(addPlayerDict)
        
        
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        
        draggedAddPlayer = nil
        
        var selectedPlayerKey = String()
        var addPlayerStruct = AddPlayerStruct()
        var selectedPoint = CGPoint()
        
        if isDobuleClick == true {
            
            guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: images) else {
                return
            }
            
            
            //TODO: check which dict key's playerview has same point
            addPlayerDict.forEach { (key,value) in
                debugPrint(key)
                debugPrint(value)
                
                // debugPrint("before \(addPlayerDict.count)")
                //TODO: get selected dict key and get all data of it
                
                guard let points = value.addPlayerViewStruct?.frame.contains(point) else { return }
                if points{
                    selectedPlayerKey = key
                    
                    selectedPoint = point
                    addPlayerViews.append(contentsOf: value.addPlayerViewsArrStruct)
                    debugPrint(addPlayerViews.last)
                    addPlayerView = value.addPlayerViewStruct           //selected playerview
                    debugPrint(selectedPlayerKey)
                    
                    
                    // show data on alertview textfield
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Player Number", message: "Enter new player Number", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addTextField { textData in
                        if addPlayerStruct.Label.text == nil{
                            textData.text = selectedPlayerKey
                            
                        }else{
                            textData.text = addPlayerStruct.Label.text
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // get changed data from textfield and save back to same dict key's playerview - Don't change key.
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                        let textfield = alert.textFields?[0]
                        addPlayerStruct.Label.text = textfield?.text!
                        
                        //   let index = self.addPlayerDict.index(forKey: selectedPlayerKey)
                        addPlayerStruct.addPlayerViewStruct = self.addPlayerView
                        self.draggedAddPlayer = self.addPlayerView
                        
                        self.addPlayerViews.removeLast()
                        self.addPlayerView?.removeFromSuperview()           //selected playerview removed from iamgeview
                        //
                        //                        //               Show on playerview
                        //
                        let rect = CGRect(x: selectedPoint.x - 20, y: selectedPoint.y - 20, width: self.addPlayerWidth, height: self.addPlayerWidth)
                        self.addPlayerView = AddPlayerView(frame: rect)
                        self.addPlayerView?.backgroundColor = .white
                        self.addPlayerView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        self.addPlayerView?.image = UIImage(named: "player")
                        self.addPlayerView?.tintColor = .systemBlue
                        
                        self.addPlayerViews.append(self.addPlayerView!)
                        self.images.addSubview(self.addPlayerView!)
                        
                        
                        
                        self.label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: rect.width / 2 - 8, y: rect.height / 2 + 5, width: 16, height: 10))
                        self.label.text = textfield?.text!
                        self.label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica" , size: 10)
                        self.label.textColor = UIColor.white
                        self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                        self.label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        self.addPlayerView!.addSubview(self.label)
                        
                        
                        
                        debugPrint(self.addPlayerDict.count)
                        self.addPlayerDict.updateValue(addPlayerStruct, forKey: selectedPlayerKey)
                        debugPrint(addPlayerStruct.addPlayerViewStruct?.frame)
                        debugPrint(self.addPlayerDict.count)
                    }))
                    self.present(alert, animated: false)
                }
                
            }
        }
        isDobuleClick = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            self.isDobuleClick = false
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

**#AddPlayerView**

```
class AddPlayerView : UIImageView{
    
    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var addPlayerPath = UIBezierPath()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup(){
        
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        
        //        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        addPlayerPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2), radius: 20, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true)
        
        shapeLayer.path = addPlayerPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a decent approach, but a couple tips...

Your class and var naming is rather confusing. For example, instead of naming your image view `images` it makes much more sense to name it something like `playingFieldImageView`. And, instead of `AddPlayerView` (which sounds like an action), just name it `PlayerView`.

You don't need to keep a separate array of player views or a dictionary of player structs... When you add a `PlayerView` as a subview of `playingFieldImageView`, you can track it with the `.subviews` property of `playingFieldImageView`.

You can move a lot of the logic you're using to manage the player view *into* the player view class... along these lines:

```
class PlayerView : UIImageView {
    
    public var playerNumber: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            playerLabel.text = "\(playerNumber)"
        }
    }
    
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    private let playerLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica" , size: 10)
        v.textColor = .white
        v.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        v.text = "0"
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    private func setup() {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.tintColor = .systemBlue
        
        if let img = UIImage(named: "player") {
            self.image = img
        } else {
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill") {
                self.image = img
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = .green
            }
        }
        
        // if using as a mask, can be any opaque color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
        // assuming you want a "round" view
        //self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
        
        // add and constrain the label as a subview
        addSubview(playerLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            playerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            playerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            playerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5.0),
        ])
        
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // update the mask path here (we have accurate bounds)
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).cgPath
    }
}
```

Now you can add a new `PlayerView` and assign its `.playerNumber` ... instead of all of the set image, add label, etc. And, when the user wants to change the "player number" you can update the `.playerNumber` property instead of removing / re-creating views.

When trying to track touches **and** taps (particularly double-taps), it is much easier to add a double-tap gesture recognizer to the subview itself.

Here's that same `PlayerView` class, but with a gesture recognizer -- and a closure to tell the controller that it was double-tapped:

```
class PlayerView : UIImageView {

    // closure to tell the controller this view was double-tapped
    public var gotDoubleTap: ((PlayerView) -> ())?
    
    public var playerNumber: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            playerLabel.text = "\(playerNumber)"
        }
    }
    
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    private let playerLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica" , size: 10)
        v.textColor = .white
        v.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        v.text = "0"
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    private func setup() {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.tintColor = .systemBlue
        
        if let img = UIImage(named: "player") {
            self.image = img
        } else {
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill") {
                self.image = img
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = .green
            }
        }
        
        // if using as a mask, can be any opaque color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
        // assuming you want a "round" view
        //self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
        
        // add and constrain the label as a subview
        addSubview(playerLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            playerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            playerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            playerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5.0),
        ])
        
        // add a double-tap gesture recognizer
        let g = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapHandler(_:)))
        g.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        addGestureRecognizer(g)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // update the mask path here (we have accurate bounds)
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).cgPath
    }
    @objc func doubleTapHandler(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // tell the controller we were double-tapped
        gotDoubleTap?(self)
    }
}
```

You can now simplify all of your touch code to handle only adding new or moving the player views.

Here's an example controller class, using the above `PlayerView` class:

```
class AddPlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //MARK: AddPlayerView Variables
    
    // we can declare this as a standard UIView
    var draggedPlayerView: UIView?
    
    let playerViewWidth : CGFloat = 40
    
    @IBOutlet var playingFieldImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playingFieldImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let draggedAddPlayer = draggedPlayerView, let point = touches.first?.location(in: playingFieldImageView) else {
            return
        }
        draggedAddPlayer.center = point
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        // Do nothing if a PlayerView is being dragged
        // or if we do not have a coordinate
        guard draggedPlayerView == nil, let point = touches.first?.location(in: playingFieldImageView) else {
            return
        }
        
        // Do not create new PlayerView if touch is in an existing circle
        // Keep the reference of the (potentially) dragged circle
        //  filter only subviews which are PlayerView class (in case we've added another subview type)
        if let draggedAddPlayer = playingFieldImageView.subviews.filter({ $0 is PlayerView }).filter({ UIBezierPath(ovalIn: $0.frame).contains(point) }).first {
            self.draggedPlayerView = draggedAddPlayer
            return
        }
        
        // Create new PlayerView
        let rect = CGRect(x: point.x - 20, y: point.y - 20, width: playerViewWidth, height: playerViewWidth)
        let newPlayerView = PlayerView(frame: rect)
        
        // give the new player the lowest available number
        //  for example, if we've created numbers:
        //      "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
        //  we want to assign "6" to the new guy
        //  but... if the user has changed the 3rd player to "12"
        //  we'll have players:
        //      "1" "2" "12" "4" "5"
        //  so we want to assign "3" to the new guy
        let nums = playingFieldImageView.subviews.compactMap{$0 as? PlayerView}.compactMap { $0.playerNumber }
        var newNum: Int = 1
        for i in 1..<nums.count + 2 {
            if !nums.contains(i) {
                newNum = i
                break
            }
        }

        newPlayerView.playerNumber = newNum
        
        // set the double-tap closure
        newPlayerView.gotDoubleTap  = { [weak self] pv in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.changePlayerNumber(pv)
        }
        
        playingFieldImageView.addSubview(newPlayerView)
        
        // The newly created view can be immediately dragged
        draggedPlayerView = newPlayerView
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        draggedPlayerView = nil
    }

    // called when a PlayerView is double-tapped
    func changePlayerNumber(_ playerView: PlayerView) {

        // show data on alertview textfield
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Player Number", message: "Enter new player Number", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { textData in
            textData.text = "\(playerView.playerNumber)"
        }
        
        // get changed data from textfield and update the playerNumber for the PlayerView
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            guard let tf = alert.textFields?.first,
               let newNumString = tf.text,
               let newNumInt = Int(newNumString),
                  newNumInt != playerView.playerNumber
            else {
                // user entered something that was not a number, or
                //  tapped OK without changing the number
                return
            }
            // don't allow a duplicate player number
            let nums = self.playingFieldImageView.subviews.compactMap{$0 as? PlayerView}.compactMap { $0.playerNumber }
            if nums.contains(newNumInt) {
                let dupAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Duplicate PLayer Number", message: "Somebody else already has number: \(newNumInt)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                dupAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                    self.changePlayerNumber(playerView)
                }))
                self.present(dupAlert, animated: true)
            } else {
                playerView.playerNumber = newNumInt
            }
        }))
        
        self.present(alert, animated: false)

    }

}
```

Comment: I need dictionary to track and save particular player's key and value.because,
I want to store player one on key "1" and player "2", when user change player 2's number, then player key "2" 's player number change.
 
as well, suppose I draw lines (line 1 and line 2) then I need to move player 2 on line 2 and player 1 to line 1.
is it possible without dictionary?

do you have any link or document so I can learn advance core graphics , cashapelayer like what I did here.

Comment: please see my question **#What I want to do?**

Comment: @Hiren - did you try running that code? You can still create a dictionary if you want... but, the added player views are already in an ordered array, so you can "find" the player by index, and/or you can use filter with a where clause to "find" a player by number.